# Creating a custom LSTMCell in Tensorflow with GPU support

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to integrate an attentional component into the LSTM model I'm creating.  Unfortunately, with tensorflow 2.3.1 that I'm using, it appears that if you subclass the LSTMCell, you have to run the model on CPU.  From the tensorflow documentation:

> CuDNN is only available at the layer level, and not at the cell level.

Which means I'm relegated to the CPU if I try something like this:

`output=keras.layers.RNN(AttentionLSTMCell(400), return_sequences=True, stateful=False)(input_layer);`

Where AttentionLSTMCell is a custom class I made that will take in some additional constants (generally an output of the previous timestamp and some new input) that will condition the output of the LSTM.  In fact, the documentation seems to suggest that even only specific conditioning is allowed.  I am about to dig into creating a full custom Layer (perhaps copy the existing and see if I can add my new inputs in call), but is there a better way?  It makes prototyping quite difficult.  Large recurrent networks are *slow* to train, especially in my case where I integrate image data as input.

Comment: I strongly suggest you look at `tensorflow addons`. It has wrappers for integrating attention mechanisms to existing cells, and abstractions for creating your own mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I looked at their code and they are using the same strategy I suggested, so I guess I'm stuck on the CPU for now unless I want to learn all the ins and outs of the GPU LSTM.    There are probably some hacks I can use with dense layers and concatenations to test out ideas as well before deploying the full model and running it for a few days if needed.  Ultimately, attention is often just adding another kernel to the input to each LSTM function, so adding it to the input is a rough approximation.  Passing output to the next recursion can't really be faked though.

Comment: You can still use GPU for other benefits, but as you mentioned rightly the advantage of CuDNN will not be there. You can check this paper if it helps you https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1166/

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have read the attention paper, and that can be added as custom layer over the hidden states with full GPU support if you're just interested in NMT (there is a full tutorial on that).  I'm actually interested in time-series analysis and I'm trying to add some other connections in time (similar to Graves 2013 writing synthesis with attention).  So, if I want to add some new internal states, such that they feed forward in novel ways, I think I have to drop to the custom cell level, and thus CPU training.  There may be ways to approximate this with custom layers though.